# Problem of multiple lags for a number of columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, error-handling, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I am trying to replicate the example of creating multiple lags for a number of columns on the `dplyr` website (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html). However, when I tried their code:

```
multilag <- function(x, lags = 1:3) {
  names(lags) <- as.character(lags)
  purrr::map_dfr(lags, lag, x = x)
}

iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("Sepal"), multilag, .unpack = TRUE)) %>%
  select(Species, starts_with("Sepal"))
```

I got this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(starts_with("Sepal"), multilag, .unpack = TRUE)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: Species = setosa.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Problem while computing column `Sepal.Length`.
Caused by error in `fn()`:
! unused argument (.unpack = TRUE)
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Anyone knows what the problem is and how to fix it?

Here is my session info:

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Have you updated `dplyr` to the latest version? `.unpack` is a new feature since `dplyr 1.1.0`.

Comment: That's it. It was the problem of using the older dplyr